# Keyboard play/stop/next/prev buttons does not work with Spotify

Tags: 11.04, spotify

I'm running the Spotify Linux Beta. My keyboard is a Logitech Illuminated something wired keyboard.

My keyboard hotkeys work with Banshee, but not with Spotify, even though controlling Spotify via the "Volume" widget in the top right of the upper panel works fine.

Comment: Same error with Simfy client :) (simfy.de)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did the following using this guide: http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2010/11/15/playing-with-d-bus-interface-of-spotify-for-linux/

You will need to install mdbus2:

```
sudo apt-get install mdbus2
```

Now you can try out to play/pause:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

To bind this to a key you need for example AutoKey.

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Create a new script and use this code:

```
system.exec_command("dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause", getOutput=False)
```

and bind it to whatever key you want to use.

Of course you can use the same method to create hotkeys for next and previous :)

This command will show you which methods that is available:

```
mdbus2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2
```

Though, I don't know what will happen if you use both banshee and spotify with the same hotkey!

Comment: Thank you Victor, I will try this when I get home from work.

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer*: I work for Spotify

This was a known missing feature of the linux client, but we added it in version 0.9.4. So while this thread is rather old, it's worth noting that it should now work. If you continue to experience problems with the media keys, then please post a message on the community forums.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Spotify. After trying all the above, I checked the keyboard bindings, and noticed I had the hotkeys unbind.

Run in terminal `unity-control-center keyboard` or go to Keyboard in your settings, go to `Shortcuts` tab then `Sound and Media`. Make sure you have bindings for your media keys.