# Openbox commands to use the media keys (play, stop, next, prev) in Spotify

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, openbox, spotify, media-buttons

Does someone know which OpenBox commands I can use with Spotify? In the following post they are using it with clementine and it doesn't work with Spotify:

[Add support for media keys (play, stop, previous and next buttons) in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585523/add-support-for-media-keys-play-stop-previous-and-next-buttons-in-lubuntu)

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out installing mdbus2 and using its commands as it is explained here:

[Keyboard play/stop/next/prev buttons does not work with Spotify](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65085/keyboard-play-stop-next-prev-buttons-does-not-work-with-spotify)

Best,